# How to access prometheus on windows when prometheus is installed on Ubuntu [Virtualbox]

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, prometheus

I havea windows laptop. On this laptop I have installed virtualbox and inside the virtualbox I have installed ubuntu server.

On the ubuntu server I have installed the Prometheus the monitoring tool. I am able to run prometheus in the terminal of ubuntu server.

This is the ip address [10.3.10.105] of my ubuntu server and prometheus is running on the port [9090]. Now I want to see the GUI of the prometheus on the windows browser. How can I see that?

I have already tried to browse on http://10.3.10.105:9090 but that does not work

[image]

Comment: looks like its not listening on an IPv4 Listener. from this page, it looks like you need to configure a listener on 0.0.0.0:9090. defaults to localhost. can you show us your prometheus.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

As *Frank Thomas* lined out, currently  your prometheus does not listen to IPv4 addresses. But IPv6 is served (see the last line of your screenshot).

Check for the IPv6 address at the prometheus server and you should be able to access it via IPv6:

```sh
# Check for the IPv6 at the server's terminal:

$  ip -br -f inet6 addr
lo               UNKNOWN        ::1/128 
enp4s0           UP             fe80::a76b:c61::3261/64


# Test the access form the client:

$  curl http://[fe80::a76b:c61::3261]:9090
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...
```

*(The IPv6 address is just an example, replace by your own)*